# Parent-Child Relationship in JSON using PlayFramework

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I need to give my Angular JS application a JSON which represents Parent-Child Relationship of to tables. 
Parent(Group):

```
+----+---------------+-------------+----------------+
| id | external_code | supplier_id | notes          |
+----+---------------+-------------+----------------+
| 19 | asdfas        |           3 | sadfa          |
| 23 | 454           |           1 | groupa1        |
| 24 | sadfas221     |           2 | asfd           |
| 25 | dsafas        |           2 | NULL           |
| 21 | 4545          |           1 | asdfasf        |
+----+---------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Child(GroupItems):

```
+----------+---------+--------+
| group_id | item_id | status |
+----------+---------+--------+
|       19 |       1 |      0 |
|       19 |       2 |      0 |
|       19 |       3 |      0 |
|       25 |       2 |      0 |
+----------+---------+--------+
```

My desired JSON should look like this:

```
[
{"groupId":"19",
"notes":"sadfa",
"extenalCode":"asdfas",
"supplierId":"2",
"itemCount":3
"items":[{"itemId": "1","status":"Created", "weight":23},
         {"itemId": "2","status":"Created", "weight":23}
         {"itemId": "3","status":"Created", "weight":23}
        ]

},

....

]
```

The question is how to insert and bind child items with parent representing JSON semantics using MySQL and PlayFramework2.0(Slick)?

Comment: Map the sequence of nested documents into several sequences of documents, one for each nesting levenl and adding the parent ids. Then use insertAll to insert the top-level items of each of these sequences?

Comment: @cvogt can you please elaborate on this? I'm really new to scala and slick API.

Comment: misread your question, you weren't asking about database inserts, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

roughly something like this:

```
val items =
  GroupItems.join(Items).on(_.itemId === _.id).run // <- query fetching items with group_ids
            .groupBy(_._1.groupId).toMap
            .mapValues(_._2) // <- mapping Map values to only items

// render groups to json and add a field items with the items (I may be wrong about Play's json api names)
val json = Group.run.map(g => Json.toJson(g) ++ JsObject("items" -> Json.toJson(items(g.id))))
```